# Android: OnFocusChangeListener not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener, onfocuschangelistener

Hi guys I want to create a search option in a fragment with collapsible/expandable EditText when the focus is changed. Here is how my class looks like:

```
@ViewById(R.id.search_text)
EditText mSearchText;

@ViewById(R.id.img_clear)
ImageButton mClearButton;

@ViewById(R.id.search_toolbar_text_container)
protected RelativeLayout editTextContainer;

SearchToolbarListener mListener;

private ValueAnimator mAnimator;

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
//the event here never gets executed 
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFocusChange(hasFocus);
    }
    mAnimator = slideAnimator(0,editTextContainer.getHeight());


    if (hasFocus && editTextContainer.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        expandSearch();
    } else {
        collapseSearch();
    }
}

public interface SearchToolbarListener {

    void onTextChanged(String newText);

    void onFocusChange(boolean isFocused);
}

public SearchToolbarView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SearchToolbarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SearchToolbarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public SearchToolbarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@AfterViews
public void init() {...}    

public void setListener(@Nullable  SearchToolbarListener mListener) {
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    mClearButton.setVisibility(charSequence.length() >= 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onTextChanged(charSequence.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

}

private void expandSearch () {
    editTextContainer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    mAnimator.start();
}

private void collapseSearch () {
    int finalHeight = editTextContainer.getHeight();
    mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            // Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
            editTextContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
}

private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new     ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            // Update Height
            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = editTextContainer
                    .getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = value;
            editTextContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    return animator;
}
}
```

And then I implement the interface in a fragment like so:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_product_search)
public class SearchableSearchFragment extends Fragment implements SearchToolbarView.SearchToolbarListener {

private static final String TAG = SearchableSearchFragment.class.getSimpleName();

@SystemService
protected LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

@ViewById(R.id.search_toolbar)
protected Toolbar mSearchToolbar;

protected SearchToolbarView mSearchToolbarView;

@Bean
protected ViewManager mViewManager;

private SearchFragment mSearchFragment;

@Bean
protected BottomNavigationHandler mBottomNavigationHandler;

@AfterViews
public void initAfterViews() {
    mSearchToolbarView = SearchToolbarView_.build(getContext());
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(String newText) {
    boolean isNumber = NumberUtils.isNumber(newText);

    if ((newText.length() >= 3 && !isNumber) || (isNumber && newText.length() == 7)) {
        this.setToolbarElevation(0);
        mSearchFragment.setSearchQuery(newText);
    } else {
        float elevationInPx = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.search_bar_elevation);
        this.setToolbarElevation(elevationInPx);
        mSearchFragment.clear();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(boolean isFocused) {
//gets called only once
    boolean ggwp = isFocused;
}
```

The problem here is that the on focus change listener does not work properly. It is being triggered only once when the fragment is started. Clicking around does not trigger it either. What am I doing wrong?